# Creating new Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CustomWorkspace - got ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: c#, roslyn

I try to create something like ConsoleClassifier in .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") Samples. (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis v0.7...) At this point I get a `ReflectionTypeLoadException`:

```
CustomWorkspace workspace = new CustomWorkspace();

ReflectionTypeLoadException
{"Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."}
LoaderExceptions: FileNotFoundException
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. A rendszer nem találja a megadott fájlt.":"Microsoft.Build, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}
```

What did I miss?

Stacktrace:

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.get_InnerCatalog()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateCatalog.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.InternalGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.InnerCatalogExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore(Type type, Type metadataViewType, String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore[T,TMetadataView](String contractName)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports[T,TMetadataView](String contractName)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports[T,TMetadataView]()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.<GetExports>b__6[TExtension,TMetadata](ExportKey _)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableInterlocked.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue](ImmutableDictionary`2& location, TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.GetExports[TExtension,TMetadata]()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.MefWorkspaceServices..ctor(MefHostServices host, Workspace workspace)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefHostServices.CreateWorkspaceServices(Workspace workspace)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace..ctor(HostServices host, String workspaceKind)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CustomWorkspace..ctor(HostServices host, String workspaceKind)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CustomWorkspace..ctor()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the VS "14" Build Tools package. You can find it in the ISO [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=509825).

Comment: I don't suppose adding a reference to `Microsoft.Net.ToolsetCompilers` would do it instead? I'd love to be able to try this within VS2013. (Or is the build tools package separate from VS itself? Confused, of Tilehurst...)

Comment: No, the toolset package enables you to use a specific version of the Roslyn compilers instead of the system installed ones.  In this case though, Roslyn references MSBuild.  Soon though, that will be factored out into a different assembly, and the majority of the Workspace stuff will be a PCL.

Comment: Great, thanks - have installed CTP4 on my Surface for the moment :)

Comment: Note that you can install just the Build Tools installer, you don't have to run the full VS install if you want to get unblocked in the meantime.